# Wordpress - Custom "plugin" that displays on a Page

Tags: wordpress

I have to build a custom plugin for a client who is using wordpress. I am dont use wordpress so I dont know how it works. I just want to understand how this will work..

I have to build them a search plugin that will be display inside a page. It will get data from an excel spreadsheet that lives on the server, so they can edit that content and it will pull all that data into the page. Is this a plugin? where do I start?
I will also need to use jQuery to do some more to the data once on the page.

Comment: If you want to improve your chances of getting a response you should go through your question history and accept answers to questions you have posted.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress plugin develop does take some work, but it is extremely well documented. I would go to the following pages in the order that they are listed:

```
http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_Resources
```

Once you've gone through those pages, you should have a lot more information on plugin development and how you might do what you are after.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question. Looking at some plugins, it seems they are using short codes to place plugins in specific pages. Here's the link in wordpress:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Answer (score 0):

For WordPress 6.0 please check this page:
[Plugin developer handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/)